# How to delete "origin/origin/master"

Tags: git, git-branch

Ok, I've created an `origin/origin/master` branch and I've pushed it. I'm scared to do some remove operations. What can I do? Is it safe to run a remove operation?

This question differs from proposed question since some tools doesn't allow `origin/master` branch (which is wrongly named on the `origin` hence makes the full name `origin/origin/master`) to be deleted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry, you can always go back with git. Make sure you have your master branch locally, then try this one:

`git push origin :origin/master`

It will delete origin/master branch on a remote "origin".

If you want to be supersafe, rename your remote from "origin" to "temp", then do:

`git push temp :origin/master`

Comment: If your remote is a Github repository, you might see a message like this:

`To github.com:username/your-repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] origin/master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/origin/master)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:username/your-repo.git'
` This is because the default branch is set to `origin/master` instead of `master`, and it is protected. Change the default branch under the "Settings" tab > "Branches".